# Warning "Call in violation of protocol"

Tags: java, hibernate, websphere

I have an application running on **IBM Websphere 8.5** and im using hibernate 4.2.8.
I am having the follow warning on server startup:

```
[3/4/14 15:20:10:725 CAT] 00000034 visitor       W com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.AnnotationInfoDefaultVisitor visitAnnotation [ com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.InfoVisitor@15024097 ] for method [ com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.info.impl.MethodInfoImpl@-210189610 ( org.hibernate.annotations.JoinColumnOrFormula.formula ) ] Name [ null ] Description [ Lorg/hibernate/annotations/JoinFormula; ] Call in violation of protocol
[3/4/14 15:20:10:725 CAT] 00000034 visitor       W com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.AnnotationInfoDefaultVisitor visitAnnotation [ com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.InfoVisitor@15024097 ] for method [ com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.info.impl.MethodInfoImpl@-482978983 ( org.hibernate.annotations.JoinColumnOrFormula.column ) ] Name [ null ] Description [ Ljavax/persistence/JoinColumn; ] Call in violation of protocol
[3/4/14 15:20:10:729 CAT] 00000034 visitor       W com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.AnnotationInfoDefaultVisitor visitAnnotation [ com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.InfoVisitor@15024097 ] for method [ com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.info.impl.MethodInfoImpl@-1529286857 ( org.hibernate.annotations.Table.foreignKey ) ] Name [ null ] Description [ Lorg/hibernate/annotations/ForeignKey; ] Call in violation of protocol
[3/4/14 15:20:10:729 CAT] 00000034 visitor       W com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.AnnotationInfoDefaultVisitor visitAnnotation [ com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.InfoVisitor@15024097 ] for method [ com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.info.impl.MethodInfoImpl@1310727123 ( org.hibernate.annotations.Table.sqlInsert ) ] Name [ null ] Description [ Lorg/hibernate/annotations/SQLInsert; ] Call in violation of protocol
[3/4/14 15:20:10:730 CAT] 00000034 visitor       W com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.AnnotationInfoDefaultVisitor visitAnnotation [ com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.InfoVisitor@15024097 ] for method [ com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.info.impl.MethodInfoImpl@251574898 ( org.hibernate.annotations.Table.sqlUpdate ) ] Name [ null ] Description [ Lorg/hibernate/annotations/SQLUpdate; ] Call in violation of protocol
[3/4/14 15:20:10:730 CAT] 00000034 visitor       W com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.AnnotationInfoDefaultVisitor visitAnnotation [ com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.InfoVisitor@15024097 ] for method [ com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.info.impl.MethodInfoImpl@-1168467436 ( org.hibernate.annotations.Table.sqlDelete ) ] Name [ null ] Description [ Lorg/hibernate/annotations/SQLDelete; ] Call in violation of protocol
[3/4/14 15:20:10:882 CAT] 00000034 visitor       W com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.AnnotationInfoDefaultVisitor visitAnnotation [ com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.InfoVisitor@-179906720 ] for method [ com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.info.impl.MethodInfoImpl@1056720732 ( javax.persistence.AssociationOverride.joinTable ) ] Name [ null ] Description [ Ljavax/persistence/JoinTable; ] Call in violation of protocol
```

] [

Does anyone know what is causing this?

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using this property:

```
...xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
```

metadata-complete="true" ...

at the head of

> web.xml

that help me!

Comment: I got the same problème with WebSphere 8.0.0.3 and it caused an OutOfMemory exception. I Updated the xsd in version 3.0 in my web.xml files and it works fine. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

The metadata parsing can be configured both at the server and application level as described at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg21381764

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on what the problem is, because I'm experiencing similar problems?

Answer (score 1):

Did you upgrade to Servlet specification 3.0 from an earlier version? This is the case for me and I am seeing the same error now.