# Hibernate Call in violation of protocol exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, websphere

I am getting Call in violation of protocol exception, when I try to deploy web application to the WebSphere 8.5. Web application is based on Spring(4.1.4.RELEASE) and Hibernate(4.2.7.Final) tech stack.

I have have placed persistance.xml into the META-INF directory.

Anybody have solution for this problem?

Exception:

> 0000003a visitor       W
>   com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.AnnotationInfoDefaultVisitor visitAnnotation
>   [ com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.InfoVisitor@511845444 ] for method [
>   com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.info.impl.MethodInfoImpl@1491394741 (
>   org.hibernate.annotations.JoinColumnOrFormula.column ) ] Name [ null ]
>   Description [ Ljavax/persistence/JoinColumn; ] Call in violation of
>   protocol
>
> 0000003a visitor       W
>   com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.AnnotationInfoDefaultVisitor visitAnnotation
>   [ com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.InfoVisitor@511845444 ] for method [
>   com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.info.impl.MethodInfoImpl@1586464341 (
>   org.hibernate.annotations.Table.foreignKey ) ] Name [ null ]
>   Description [ Lorg/hibernate/annotations/ForeignKey; ] Call in
>   violation of protocol

Comment: have you found the problem?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22173885/warning-call-in-violation-of-protocol

Answer (score 0):

Please check your web.xml schema Location & meta data, create a web application of similar kind in which your facing the issue and copy the basic structure of the web.xml from this newly created app and place your actual web.xml stuff from old app. Then place the modified web.xml